# PDO Mysql получить ид если есть уже запись

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос в базу

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO type_filters (name)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT :name) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM type_filters WHERE name = :name
) LIMIT 1";




$db = new \Opti\DataBase();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
      $result =  $stmt->execute();

        echo $result; // всегда 1
```

Как мне всегда получать ид не зависимо от того есть ли запись или она новая.

Answer (score 0):

В переменную `$result` прилетает результат запроса, либо он выполнен - 1, если что-то пошло не так то - 0

Получить `id` можно так
`$id = $db->lastInsertId();`

здесь похожий вопрос, можете почитать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted